# How to restrict the date selected

Tags: forms, date, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

How to disable dates greater than today in a DateEdit control in an AX form?

Is possible with a date extended data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict date ranges on the extended data type level.

You will have to validate the entered date.

The method where to validate (preferred method first):

1. `validateField` on table
2. `validateWrite` on table (if comparing two entered dates)
3. `validate` on form field
4. `validate` on form control

Also see [method sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa876155%28v=ax.10%29.aspx).